# Configuring Apache in AWS Lightsail instance for Server Sent Events in PHP

Tags: php, apache, bitnami

I'm trying to get Server Sent Events working on AWS Lightsail instance (bitnami). Here is the PHP code I'm testing with:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

while (true) {
    $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
    echo 'data: {"time": "' . $curDate . '"}';
    echo "\n\n";
    
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

However, when opening this page in browser, server "sleeps" for a 20-30 seconds, and then prints all the updates and keep going in that way. I disabled cache following [this guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/disable-cache/).

The PHP code is OK, it works on another LAMP machine...

Any ideas what to tweak in apache to disable caching?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. I understand that when you disabled the cache, you restarted all the services after editing the conf files, right? I understand you did the same in the other LAMP machines. You can take a look at the Apache's log file (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log`) to see if there is any error there.

Comment: Hi @JotaMartos, yes I have restarted all the services... No errors in error_log, everything works fine, just ignoring `flush()` and `ob_flush()` commands. I applied the dirty fix: echoing `str_pad('', 4096)` with every message to fill up the buffer and send a message immediately. I don't like it, but ran out of smarter ideas...